# Making a multiple call to Mango db document without losing any request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the code where I increment the value by 1 to update the document. Multiplying requests at the same time causes some data to be lost.

For example: Let’s assume that our document attribute value is 0.
Therefore:

```
Users document:
    {
    name : abc
    place : bangalore
    userLimits : {
        daily: 10
        daily_Usage: 0
       }
    }
```

This scenario involves two processes/requests reading the same document, performing the operation, and updating it. As a result, both processes read the same data. After the two processes complete their tasks, the final output for Visitors is 1, and the expected output is 2.

How can I avoid this?

```
lists.map(async (list) => { 
      let userInfo = await Users.find({ name: "abc"});  //assuming just one user, I am gonna make it dynamic, once code works
      let query = { name: userInfo[0].name}
      let update = { "userLimits.$.daily_Usage": userInfo[0].userLimits.inflightAvailable+1  }; 
      await Users.findOneAndUpdate(query, update)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error");
    });
```

I have tried to use $inc operator. However, i need help with Map function.
Here is the flow.
Make a multiple request to update, no request should miss.

I am new to this concept, please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {name: "abc"},
  {$inc: {"userLimits.daily_Usage": 1}}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cg6Sfs-lJnx)

You do want to use `$inc` to make it an atomic operation, So if you call it multiple times (x times) on parallel it will be increased multiple times (increased by x in your case).

`"userLimits.$.daily_Usage"` is relevant if `userLimits` is an array